# socket.io emit specific transports

Tags: apache-flex, socket.io

can socket.io emit in one transport style then in another?

```
socket.emit('my event',{data:'something'},{transports: ['websocket','xhr-polling']});
socket.emit('my event',{data:'somethingelse'},{transports: ['flashsocket']});
```

my reason is that i want to create a flex .swf with FlashSocket.IO that talks to my server app.js the same as my client.html  javascript does.

Comment: Did you try it before asking the question?  If so, did you run into problems?  What were the problems?

Comment: i haven't set up the flash part yet. trying to gather as much info at this stage. It doesn't mention it in the socket.io wiki but it does look like you can specify via the client 'the transports', but in the case of the server switching style I will try this as soon as i can; unless someone replies and says it is a silly idea :p

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use namespace and for your js client, connect to namespace a. For your flex client, connect to namespace b. This way you can manage your client easier and have much more clear picture on what you do with each group. You can also try something like this:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

var mySocket;
var chat = io
  .of('/chat')
  .on('connection', function (socket) {
    mySocket = socket;
    socket.emit('a message', {
        that: 'only'
      , '/chat': 'will get'
    });
  });

var mySocket2;
var chat2 = io
  .of('/chat2')
  .on('connection', function (socket) {
    mySocket2 = socket;
    socket.emit('a message', {
        that: 'only'
      , '/chat2': 'will get'
    });
  });

function myEmit(channel, msg) {
  if (channel == 'chat1')
    mySocket.emit(msg);
  else if (channel == 'chat2')
    mySocket2.emit(msg)
}
```

Comment: that has nothing to do with transports